# Organize Date and Hours in RStudio

Tags: r, time, hour, zone

I have a dataset with different entries for hours. Example 23:59 and 11:59PM.
I have tried using the command below but did not work. It is changing only the time that appears PM and AM and making NA in other rows

t <- "1:36:22 PM"
as.POSIXlt(t, format = "%H:%M:%S")

Comment: You can use `as.POSIXct("11:59 PM", format = "%I:%M %p")`

Comment: I tried but is changing only the rows with this format and making other rows as "NA"